# Multi Div Issues with clicking individually and affecting removable classes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have few divs that will act like independent "buttons" with different products and services. I also created a javascript code that allows you to change the class of the subproducts for each product button. they only show if you click on a certain product. I'm experimenting two issues:

1- I need only to affect the selected one, right now, since they're called the same, is opening them all.

Also, once I open the prefered one, I want the rest to keep the Height: auto, right now they're increasing in size to the reference or the bigger one.

Someone can help me to solve this? this is my actual code:

HTML

```
<div id="quotingWrapper">
        <div id="quotingArea2">
          <div id="item">
            <h4 class="itemText">Product 1</h4>
                <div class="itemHidden">
                    <h4 class="itemText">First Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Second Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Third Option</h4>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="item">
            <h4 class="itemText">Product 2</h4>
                <div class="itemHidden">
                    <h4 class="itemText">First Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Second Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Third Option</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="item">
            <h4 class="itemText">Product 3</h4>
                <div class="itemHidden">
                    <h4 class="itemText">First Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Second Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Third Option</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="item">
            <h4 class="itemText">Product 4</h4>
                <div class="itemHidden">
                    <h4 class="itemText">First Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Second Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Third Option</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="item">
            <h4 class="itemText">Product 5</h4>
                <div class="itemHidden">
                    <h4 class="itemText">First Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Second Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Third Option</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="item">
            <h4 class="itemText">Product 6</h4>
                <div class="itemHidden">
                    <h4 class="itemText">First Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Second Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Third Option</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="item">
            <h4 class="itemText">Product 7</h4>
                <div class="itemHidden">
                    <h4 class="itemText">First Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Second Option</h4>
                    <h4 class="itemText">Third Option</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #fff;
}

#quotingWrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 2000px;
background-color: #662d91;
color: #fff;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}

#quotingArea2 {
width: 90%;
background-color: pink;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
color: ;
margin:0 auto;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#item {
width: 23%;
height: auto;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-size:18px;
background-color: #3c1e57;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 1%;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#item:hover {
background-color: #492362;
}

.itemHidden {
width: 100%;
height: 0px;
position: relative;
background-color: #8345ae;
overflow: hidden;
transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.itemHidden2 {
height: auto;
transition: height 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.itemText {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 5px;
font-size: 18px;
}

@media all and (max-width:1000px) {

#item {
width: 31.3%;
}

}

@media all and (max-width:650px) {

#item {
width: 48%;
}

}

@media all and (max-width:500px) {

#item {
width: 100%;
}

}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#item').click( function() {
$(".itemHidden").toggleClass("itemHidden2");
} );
```

Someone can guide me:)!?

Comment: ID's are meant to be unique per element.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a function on each div

```
<div id="quotingWrapper">
<div id="quotingArea2">
    <div id="item" onclick="f(this);">
        <h4 class="itemText">Product 1</h4>
        <div class="itemHidden">
            <h4 class="itemText">First Option</h4>
            <h4 class="itemText">Second Option</h4>
            <h4 class="itemText">Third Option</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and add a function that each div calls

```
var prevEle;

function f(ele) {   
    $(ele).find(".itemHidden").toggleClass("itemHidden2");

    if (prevEle !== undefined) {
        $(prevEle).find(".itemHidden").toggleClass("itemHidden2");
    }
    prevEle = ele;
}
```

you really need unique id's though. for some of this, the js is going through all the divs to manipulate them and there's only so much you can do.

https://jsfiddle.net/qts0Lpmq/